# Elasticsearch pagination with Java and Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to paginate the results of a query to sent them to a front-end. This front-end will be requesting additional pages of data in the next few minutes. I have been reading the official documentation about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html).

I understand that `search_after` + `pit_id` would satisfy my need.

The problem appears when I want to implement this with Java and spring-data-elasticsearch. I have been looking into the spring-data-elasticsearch doc but I was not able to find anything about `search_after` or `pit_id`.

So, my question is, is this use case supported by spring-data-elasticsearch or is it possible to do a kind of workaround to achieve it?
Is there any example of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search_after` is not currently supported, there is [an issue for that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1143).

Neither is the `pit` point in time API. You might create an issue for that if you want.

Besides that, you can use Spring Data Repository functions for paging by passing in a `Pageable` parameter, you can uses paging when using the `(Reactive)ElasticsearchTemplate` classes as well.